# Javascript chat message grouping

Tags: javascript, angularjs, postgresql, chat, messaging

The title sucks, I know, so I'll try to describe what I'm trying to accomplish.

I have a simple direct message chat setup with node/angular/postgres(sequelize.js). Each message a user sends is stored in a messages table in the database and that message object is sent back to the browser after the message is saved.

My end goal is if user Bobby sends a direct message to Sally one after another the messages will group under Bob's name.

If you've used slack or gitter they do this *exact* behavior.

For example:

```
Bobby: hi sally.
       how are you?
       nice day we are having.

Sally: hi bob.
       nice weather indeed.

Bobby: ok, see ya!

Sally: bye!
```

One idea I have is each chat message is given a group_id by default that is stored in the database. If Bobby sends 3 messages in a row each message has a corresponding group id.

I'm not really sure how to accomplish this and I know this isn't really bleeding edge technology. I'm just curious to see how others have solved this problem.

The main thing is if the user refreshes the page the grouping has to persist.

Comment: seems like you can do that at the last part before it's shown to the user. if the sender of the incoming message is the same as the last sender (and it's under say 90 seconds old), append to the last message group, otherwise start a new group and append the name along with the message. you can follow these rule live or all at once upon load.

Comment: That's what I was thinking, I am adding a time limit (5 mins) but I left that out just to get the point across.